# error Incorrect syntax near 'LoginName'. in c#

Tags: c#

i'm getting this error Incorrect syntax near 'LoginName'. in c#

```
public Data Table Select Data(string stored_Procedure,sqlParameter[] para)
{
  SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand();
  sqlCom.CommandText = stored_Procedure;
  sqlCom.Connection = con;
  if(para!=null)
  {
      for(int i =0;i<para.Length;i++)
      {

         sqlCom.Parameters.Add(para[i]);
      }
  }
   SqlDataAdapter dt = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCom);
   DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Fill(Dt);
   return Dt;
}
```

Comment: how are you calling ?

Comment: can we see the stored procedure command?

Comment: and parameters plus stored procedure definition

Comment: Also use `using` statement to dispose your connection, command and adapters. BTW, your return type and method names doesn't have white space. It should be as `public DataTable SelectData(...`

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: ALTER PROC [dbo].[LoginName]
 @UserName varchar(50),@password varchar(50)
AS
 SELECT * from LoginUsers where User_Name=@UserName and @Password=password;

Comment: class Login
    {
        public DataTable Loginusers(string id,string pass)
        {
                    DALayer.DALayer DAL = new DALayer.DALayer();
            SqlParameter[] para = new SqlParameter[2];
            para[0] = new SqlParameter("@User_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, (50));
            para[0].Value = id;
            para[1] = new SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, (50));
            para[1].Value = pass;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = DAL.SelectData("LoginName", para);
            return dt;
        }

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify [`CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx)(default is `Text`):

```
sqlCom.CommandText = stored_Procedure; // name of stored-Procedure;
sqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

The reason for your issue was that your connection string didn't target the right database. Then the stored-procedure can't be found(*"Could not find stored procedure 'Login Name'"*).

Comment: after i modified command type to stored procedure i got error like  Could not find stored procedure 'Login Name'.;

Comment: you need to check if stored procedure exists in DB.(Clear from exception message).

Comment: @SaidVetch: maybe a different shema. We can't know without more informations.

Comment: Stored Procedure is Existing in DB  SO what shall id do;

Comment: @SaidVetch: are you sure that the conection string targets the correct database and that the SP uses the dbo schema?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter :- thank you Very much Connection string to database Wasn't right "as should be" now I've just updated. thanks a lot .

Comment: @SaidVetch: Updated my answer. Glad i could help. Consider to acept the answer.